# Action Bar - Missing Menu

Tags: java, android, android-studio

As I am new to Android Studio I have one question to ask here and I hope You guys don't mind.

So I created action menu that should have 3 doots at right upper end and that should call menu.
Anyway here is my menu:

[image]

In my main activity I am able to see menu but I am not able to see title and 3 doots.

Code of my main.java class (LocationInit):

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.GoogleMaps:
                Intent googlemaps = new Intent(this, googlemaps.class);
                startActivity(googlemaps);
                break;
            case R.id.Settings:
                Intent settings = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(settings);
                break;
            case R.id.LastLocation:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Help", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Finally my app_bar.xml (XML Of action bar):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/CustomToolbarStyle"
    app:popupTheme="@style/CustomPopupTheme">



</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

[image]

Comment: if <ToolBar> is not used then remove it. it override your toolbar so 3 dots is not displayed.

Comment: @DharaJani - Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean, from where I should remove <ToolBar>?

Comment: I am telling about app_bar.xml .

Answer (score 0):

**main_menu.xml** 
code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_main_setting"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:title="Setting" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_main_setting2"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:title="Setting" />

</menu>
```

and just override **onCreateOptionsMenu** like this in your MainPage.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

and in **onCreate()** add this

```
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.main_manu);
```

Comment: I answered with comment so You are able to check it out easier.